# Need to print different values of Child Node in separate lines in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement to print one row for Each Bonus which employee received along with Salary and Allowances.
Please see the XML from the report -
(Bonus_Assignment is the node which I need to print in different line for each bonus)

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/XMLNAME_1475b_-_Amit">
  <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary>OfferSalary</wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary>
    <wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus>OfferBonus</wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus>
    <wd:Allowance_Assignments>
      <wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance>OffersAutoAllowance</wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance>
      <wd:Allowance_Amount>700</wd:Allowance_Amount>
      <wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance wd:Descriptor="USA Car Allowance">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">32bd01e62b27101f0c5d34bc3e398d93</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Compensation_Plan_ID">USA_Car_Allowance</wd:ID>
      </wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance>
    </wd:Allowance_Assignments>
    <wd:Candidate_ID>C02271</wd:Candidate_ID>
    <wd:Job_Application wd:Descriptor="Stefen Salvatore (Referral) - R00010 Sr Analyst Delivery Specialist_175328BR (C02271)">
      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">c820a3cdb761900dcf51dc132e290529</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Application_ID">JOB_APPLICATION-6-2270</wd:ID>
    </wd:Job_Application>
    <wd:Worker_Sub-Type wd:Descriptor="Regular">
      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc914f6ed6aa101d83de5572d1e46422</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
    </wd:Worker_Sub-Type>
    <wd:Job_Application_Offer_Status wd:Descriptor="Offer Accepted">
      <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc914f6ed6aa101e1a6e235e35f5706c</wd:ID>
      <wd:ID wd:type="Offer_Status_ID">OFFER_STATUS_Offer_Accepted</wd:ID>
    </wd:Job_Application_Offer_Status>
    <wd:Job_Requisition>
      <wd:Employee_Num>R00010</wd:Employee_Num>
      <wd:Currency_Code wd:Descriptor="AUD">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">8a96ee707a264afe888d90ef93253305</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Currency_ID">AUD</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Currency_Numeric_Code">036</wd:ID>
      </wd:Currency_Code>
      <wd:Worker_Type wd:Descriptor="Regular">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">bc914f6ed6aa101d83de5572d1e46422</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Employee_Type_ID">Regular</wd:ID>
      </wd:Worker_Type>
      <wd:Req_Salary>0</wd:Req_Salary>
      <wd:Req_Bonus>0</wd:Req_Bonus>
      <wd:Req_Allowance>0</wd:Req_Allowance>
      <wd:Bonus_Effective_Date>2017-01-19-08:00</wd:Bonus_Effective_Date>
    </wd:Job_Requisition>
    <wd:Salary_Assignments>
      <wd:Salary_Amount>75000</wd:Salary_Amount>
      <wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Salary wd:Descriptor="Base Salary">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">32bd01e62b27101f0c622c47a20f911a</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Compensation_Plan_ID">Base_Salary</wd:ID>
      </wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Salary>
    </wd:Salary_Assignments>
    <wd:Bonus_Assignments>
      <wd:Bonus_Amount>11199.56</wd:Bonus_Amount>
      <wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus wd:Descriptor="IBP Semi-Annual EMC">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">32bd01e62b27101f0c6300373ce89192</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Compensation_Plan_ID">IBP_Semi-Annual_EMC</wd:ID>
      </wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus>
    </wd:Bonus_Assignments>
    <wd:Bonus_Assignments>
      <wd:Bonus_Amount>22399.11</wd:Bonus_Amount>
      <wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus wd:Descriptor="IBP Corporate">
        <wd:ID wd:type="WID">32bd01e62b27101f0c631f69f96491bd</wd:ID>
        <wd:ID wd:type="Compensation_Plan_ID">IBP_Corporate</wd:ID>
      </wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus>
    </wd:Bonus_Assignments>
  </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Current result:

```
"OfferSalary"   R00010  AUD 0   "Base Salary"       75000  
"OfferBonus"    R00010  AUD     "IBP Semi-Annual IBP Corporate"     11199.56 22399.11  
"OffersAutoAllowance"   R00010  AUD         "USA Car Allowance"     700
```

Expected -

```
"OfferSalary"   R00010  AUD 0   "Base Salary"       75000  
"OfferBonus"    R00010  AUD     "IBP Semi-Annual"       11199.56  
"OfferBonus"    R00010  AUD     "IBP Corporate"     22399.11  
"OffersAutoAllowance"   R00010  AUD         "USA Car Allowance"     700
```

Current XSLT

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/XMLNAME_1475b_-_Amit" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="Tab" select="'&#x9;'" />
  <xsl:variable name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
      <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary">
          <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferSalary" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="0" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Salary_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Salary/@wd:Descriptor" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="''" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
      <xsl:value-of select="wd:Salary_Assignments/wd:Salary_Amount" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      <xsl:if test="wd:Bonus_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus/@wd:Descriptor != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferBonus" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Bonus_Incl_Excl_Bonus" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Bonus_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus/@wd:Descriptor" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Bonus_Effective_Date" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Bonus_Assignments/wd:Bonus_Amount" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="wd:Allowance_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance/@wd:Descriptor != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="(wd:Allowance_Assignments/wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance) and (wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Worker_Type/@wd:Descriptor != 'Fixed Term')">
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Allowance_Assignments/wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Allowance_Assignments/Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferAllowance" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="''" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Bonus_Incl_Excl_Allowance" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Allowance_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance/@wd:Descriptor" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:text />
        <xsl:value-of select="$Tab" />
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Allowance_Assignments/wd:Allowance_Amount" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: The Stack Overflow editor has a live preview and a help section. Please format your question properly. That can't be too hard.

Comment: Yes. This is my first post on Stack Overflow.. I tried to put in best possible format.. :)

Comment: Much better, thank you! :) Your current XSLT is still missing. BTW: Formatting sections of code in bold does not work, I think the `**` should be removed.

Comment: Done. I added my current XSLT for review.

Comment: Great! I've formatted the remaining 10%, it's fine now.

Comment: Thanks you so much.. It looks perfect.. (at least my question in this post) :)

Comment: No, it's not fine: the last closing tag `</wd:Report_Data>` is cut off. More importantly, the provided stylesheet does **not** produce the claimed result. And there is no explanation regarding the logic that needs to be applied here. I suggest you reduce the example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem (see: [mcve]) and explain what are you trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use template matching.

You have multiple `wd:Bonus_Assignments` elements that each should be transformed into an output line.

That's the perfect situation for an `<xsl:apply-templates>`/`<xsl:template>` pair.

Compare (also note the slightly changed relative paths in the templates):

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/XMLNAME_1475b_-_Amit" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="Tab" select="'&#x9;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:variable name="newline" select="'&#xA;'" />

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Entry" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferSalary" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>l
                <xsl:value-of select="Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferSalary" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, 0)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, $quote, wd:Salary_Assignments/wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Salary/@wd:Descriptor, $quote)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, '')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, wd:Salary_Assignments/wd:Salary_Amount)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />

        <!-- here ****************************************************** -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Bonus_Assignments[wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus/@wd:Descriptor != '']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Allowance_Assignments[wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance/@wd:Descriptor != '']" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Bonus_Assignments">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus">
                <xsl:value-of select="../wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferBonus" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="../Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferBonus" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Bonus_Incl_Excl_Bonus)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, $quote, wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Bonus/@wd:Descriptor, $quote)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Bonus_Effective_Date)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, wd:Bonus_Amount)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wd:Allowance_Assignments">
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance and ../wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Worker_Type/@wd:Descriptor != 'Fixed Term'">
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_OfferAllowance" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:Employee_Compensation_Type_TOfferAllowance" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Employee_Num)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Job_Requisition/wd:Currency_Code/@wd:Descriptor)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, ../wd:Bonus_Incl_Excl_Allowance)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, $quote, wd:Flsa_Status_Code_Allowance/@wd:Descriptor, $quote)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, '')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($Tab, wd:Allowance_Amount)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$newline" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Result:

```
"OfferSalary"   R00010  AUD 0   "Base Salary"       75000
"OfferBonus"    R00010  AUD     "IBP Semi-Annual EMC"       11199.56
"OfferBonus"    R00010  AUD     "IBP Corporate"     22399.11
"OffersAutoAllowance"   R00010  AUD     "USA Car Allowance"     700
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak ! this solution has solve the problem. :).. however I am getting one small issue in the output.. output starting from line#2 with with some space before first column... I tried and didnt find any unsual linebreak in xslt.. let me know if you have any clue. Access the given link for the output screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzV1JJaHsm31bE5UcU1DdFA4OGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Change `<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Entry">` to `<xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Entry">`.

Comment: @Tomalak...Sorry, it didn't work.. this has messed up all the data and alignment..please see the screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzV1JJaHsm31UUxMSzFqd0o3Qk0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah, `<wd:Report_Entry>` is not the top-most element in your XML, but `<wd:Report_Data>`. I've modified the code above. It now has a `<xsl:template match="/*">` which matches the top-most element (regardless of name) and then directs the XSLT engine to process only `<wd:Report_Entry>` elements and nothing else. Background: The undesired whitespace came through from your XML due to [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) which govern the default behavior of XSLT. Making specific templates overrides those rules. The original answer missed a specific starting rule.

Comment: This is perfect. I will go through with the documentation and learn more about XSLT templates. Appreciate your all support to resolve this issue. :)